# Does Raptor rocket engine of SpaceX include a cracker or fuel conversion system to crack the hydrocarbon fuel into its constituents?

Tags: spacex, rockets, nasa, engines, raptor

1. In the Raptor rocket engine, where is the hot turbine exhaust gas transferred, when gaseous fuel arrives from the heat exchanger?
2. Does the Raptor rocket engine include a cracker or fuel conversion system to crack the hydrocarbon fuel into its constituents?

Comment: Cracking in context of hydrocarbons typically means breaking longer hydrocarbon chains into smaller, more volatile chains. Methane (which is Raptor fuel) is the simplest of hydrocarbons, one carbon atom and four hydrogens. No simpler hydrocarbons exist for methane to be cracked into.

Answer (score 6):

1. The [Raptor is a full-flow staged combustion engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Raptor). The turbine exhaust gases go into the main combustion chamber.
2. No. The fuel is burned without conversion. No conversion is necessary: the methane in the tank can be burned without modification.